# Why are my SQL queries not returning anything? Why does one query succeed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, health-monitoring

### Problem

The sql queries I am running on my server are not always returning back results? This doesn't make sense. EDIT: My problem is why are two queries below returning empty (no data)? They should return data like my other query. Many queries have been doing this to me today and I don't know where even to begin looking for the cause.

I'm a developer that was asked to look into our TFS2013 sql server. It isn't my domain knowledge, but I have learned a lot today. Unfortunately, that hasn't been enough to figure out my original problem. I keep running into new ones. I've had a tough time trying to get a sql server to help me out. It feels like [this](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/e5/e5a1c1544098c62f8becabf81bbe2ca57d0cba1f03f63b6a9d2d3b9d9c25b0be.jpg).

### Details

[image: Empty]

That's empty. Why? As I learned, master should be a keyword that invokes the master db on sql server? huh?

```
SELECT 
@@SERVERNAME as ServerName,
a.session_id,
datediff(ss, a.Start_Time, getdate()) as seconds, 
a.wait_type, 
a.wait_time, 
m.requested_memory_kb / 1024 as requestedMB,
a.granted_query_memory, 
m.dop,
a.command,
d.Name as DBName, 
a.blocking_session_id as blockedby, 
LTRIM(b.text) as sproc, 
substring(b.text, a.statement_start_offset /2, 
CASE WHEN 
    (a.statement_end_offset - a.statement_start_offset) / 2 > 0 
    THEN 
    (a.statement_end_offset - a.statement_start_offset) / 2
    ELSE 1 
END) as stmt, 
a.last_wait_type,
a.reads, 
a.writes,
a.logical_reads, 
a.cpu_time
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_requests a with (NOLOCK)
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(a.sql_handle) b
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants m (NOLOCK)
    on m.session_id = a.session_id
    and m.request_id = a.request_id
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.databases d
    ON d.database_id = a.database_id
WHERE 
    a.session_id > 50 
    AND a.session_id <> @@spid 
ORDER BY
    datediff(ss, a.Start_Time, getdate()) DESC
```

Gives me the following blank result: 
[image]

Then, I do this and I get something:

[image]

What? Why is this working? Is it because I am referencing some sys.dm_os stuff? But I am referencing sys in my huge query too. Completely confused.

### Attempts

This is why I am reaching out to you professionals. I need help. I obtained the second, very large query, from a TFS2013 pro book which claims to work on **ANY** sql server. It's not giving me any useful feedback. The first query I shared is a must and seems to be working for others.

Am I missing a permission to run certain queries on SQL2012? Or am I being really foolish and not realize I am using generic query terms and need to make it more specific?

Comment: Every query you posted is using different views, what is the problem?

Comment: Views? How so? I'm no dba, but based on what I have learned I have not used CREATE VIEW command at all. These are separate sql queries. For example, the problem is that @@SERVERNAME as Servername query is not returning any data. Just fields names.

Comment: sys.dm_exec_requests is a view, as is sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx

Comment: Fair enough. But as I see the query as written, it is querying from the view(see: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp)? So it should work. I didn't write that query either. It was in the Pro TFS2013 book and sold as this hot shot do everything diagnostic query. Are you implying that the query given in the book is wrong (and hence no data)?

Comment: Keep in mind that sys.dm_exec_requests only return currently executing query, it won't show query that is already executed.

Answer (score 1):

Those queries will return no data if your server isn't doing anything. It starts with the view `sys.dm_exec_requests` which lists all requests that are currently being executed against your server.

Note it also contains the line:

```
AND a.session_id <> @@spid
```

The function `@@spid` returns the ID of your session, so means the query is excluding data on the query that yo are running to get this data, makes sense as you don't really care about it. However, if you want the query to always return rows, remove that line and you will see at least 1 entry every time you run it.